# How do I change a date to YYYYMMDD in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

I have the below code which works out the date 6 months ago from todays date.

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import date

six_months = date.today() + relativedelta(months=-6)
```

However I would like six_months to be in "%Y%m%d" format.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: See the newest answer in the 'This question already has an answer here' link.

Answer (score 17):

You're looking for `strftime`.

```
six_months.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

This should do the job for you.